# How to remove elements from selection when using PHP Simple HTML Dom library

Tags: php, parsing, simplexml

I am using `PHP Simple HTML Dom` library. I can obtain the element that I want. But this element contains other elements that I want to remove from selection.

```
[elem]
    include this data
    [elem]exclude this data[elem]
[elem]
```

If it is possible please show an example.

Comment: Looking at the simple html DOM API, it doesn't seem to have xml dom methods for removal and addition that you would need to do this .. is there any reason you can't use `DOMDocument`?

Comment: @tandu So with `DOMDocument` is possible???

Answer (score 0):

xml

```
<elem>
   include this data
   <elem>exclude this data</elem>
</elem>
```

php -- Pure DOMDocument solution:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load('xml.xml');
$node = $dom->getElementsByTagName('elem')->item(0);
$child = $node->getElementsByTagName('elem')->item(0);
$node->removeChild($child);
echo $dom->saveXml();
```

php -- SimpleXML with DOMDocument

```
$doc = simplexml_load_file('xml.xml');

$toremove = $doc->elem;
$dom = dom_import_simplexml($toremove);
$dom->parentNode->removeChild($dom);

echo $doc->asXml();
```